# username is null in DotNetOpenAuth2.ResourceServer.VerifyAccess

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I have implemented an authorization server based on the sample and am receiving an access token in response to client credentials request. From my understanding this access token has a null username because it is not tied to a user.

I have implemented a resource server also based on the sample. When I try to validate the access token in my wcf server (resource server) in OAuthAuthorizationManager.VerifyOAuth2 I get an ArgumentNullException for username from

```
var error = resourceServer.VerifyAccess(httpRequestInfo, out result);
```

How can I modify OAuthAuthorizationManager to allow a null username?

Do I create a generic principal on the fly and assign it to the scope in the token.
i.e. should I use

```
var error = resourceServer.VerifyAccess(httpRequestInfo, out userName, out scope);
```

instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with DotNetOpenAuth v4.0.  v4.1 has this issue fixed.  It's not released yet, but you can snag a copy from NuGet if you point it at this channel: 
http://teamcity.dotnetopenauth.net:82/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc